# Django Info logging doesn't rotate anymore

Tags: python, django, logging, uwsgi

I modified the logging system in my Django app, so to log some warning messages in some situations. These new warning log files work correctly, but the default log info files have stopped rotating, and now all messages goes to the same .log file, instead of rotate each day and compress old files, and delete older ones. I'm using Django 1.9 running in uWSGI and Nginx. Nginx log files work just fine. This is how the logging part of my settings file looks like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'hc': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s \n%(message)s'
        },
        'verbose': {
        'format': ' [%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s'
    },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'backupCount': 50,
            'when': "D",
            'interval': 1,
            'filename': '/var/log/django/error.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'alarm': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'backupCount': 50,
            'when': "D",
            'interval': 1,
            'filename': '/var/log/django/warningalarm.log',
            'formatter': 'hc'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['error'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'application': {
            'handlers': ['alarm'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
```

and this is the uwsgi .ini file for my app:

```
[uwsgi]
# Define variables 
project = %n

# Config 
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

socket = /tmp/app.sock
master = true
no-orphans = true

chdir = /home/deploy/App
module = App.wsgi:application
virtualenv = /url/to/virtualenvs/App

logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%(project).log
```

Is there any way to recover the default behavior of the django/uwswi logging so the  files start rotating and compress as before?

Comment: you could always configure the regular logrotate http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html